# How can Voldemort die in this situation?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

> ‘But if Voldemort used the Killing Curse,’ Harry started again, ‘and nobody died for me this time – how can I be alive?’
>   ‘I think you know,’ said Dumbledore. ‘Think back. Remember what he did, in his ignorance, in his greed and his cruelty.’
>   ...
>   ‘He took my blood,’ said Harry.
>   ‘Precisely!’ said Dumbledore. ‘He took your blood and rebuilt his living body with it! Your blood in his veins, Harry, Lily’s protection inside both of you! He tethered you to life while he lives!’
>   ‘I live ... while he lives? But I thought ... I thought it was the other way round! I thought we both had to die? Or is it the same thing?’

If it's so then can Voldemort not die because Harry's blood once flowed through Voldemort’s veins? Someone please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

## The protection only tied *Harry* to life.

On J.K. Rowling’s website, she describes the sacrifice protection as Lily’s protective power over Harry. The sacrifice protection only tied Harry to life, not the Dark Lord, since its power specifically protects Harry. So although the Dark Lord took it to rebuild his body, it still only protected Harry, so only tied Harry to life while it existed outside of him.

> Having taken Harry’s blood into himself, Voldemort is keeping alive Lily’s protective power over Harry. So Voldemort himself acts almost like a Horcrux for Harry – except that the power of Lily’s sacrifice is a positive force that not only continues to tether Harry to life, but gives Voldemort himself one last chance (Dumbledore refers to this last hope in chapter 35). Voldemort has unwittingly put a few drops of goodness back inside himself; if he had repented, he could have been healed more deeply than anyone would have supposed. But, of course, he refused to feel remorse. 
> <sub><sup>*[- FAQ on J.K. Rowling’s website](https://content.time.com/time/specials/2007/article/0,28804,1690753_1695388_1695569,00.html)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord wasn’t tied to life in any way by having used Harry’s blood to rebuild his body with.

Comment: Wonder if Wormtail checked Harry's blood type before doing the transfusion into Voldey. *"Oh, you're not compatible with blood type AB+? Looks like you're going into renal failure and shock, Mister Dark Lord!"*